# git-svn died of signal 10 on OSX

Tags: git, svn, macos, git-svn

I asked this question [originally on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/176840/git-svn-died-of-signal-10-on-osx), but it looks like I'm much more likely to get an answer here. I have git and git-svn installed via [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). I try to do the following:

```
$ git svn init http://myserver/myrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in checkout/.git/
$ git svn fetch
error: git-svn died of signal 10
```

Why is git-svn failing? How can I fix this? I have the repo already checked out via vanilla SVN, so there shouldn't be any access or permissions issues.

Comment: git-svn is actually perl... the script should be installed somewhere like `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn` You could probably turn on the perl debugger (either edit the file and add `-d` on the shebang line, or run it as `perl -d /path/to/git-svn`) and get a lot more information.

Comment: You could also run it though something like this script: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2006/02/msg81574.html and find exactly the line it dies on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same problem with updated 1.6 [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/) subversion binaries.  Make sure you have the following environment variables set in ~/.profile:

```
 export PATH=/path/to/svn/bin:....
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/svn/lib:...
 export PERL5LIB=/path/to/svn/lib/svn-perl:...
```

If you don't set all these, there will be some mismatch between your updated libs and the native Leopard libs, and *git-svn* will fail.

Or are you still using the native subversion 1.5 that came with Leopard?

Comment: Thanks. It's been a year so I don't remember where things stood but your answer sounds great.