# git-svn: On Mac, "error: git-svn died of signal 6" while using git svn dcommit

Tags: macos, git, svn

I'm using git 1.8 (from MacPorts) on Mac OS X 10.8. svn version 1.7.7.
I have a remote repo recently upgraded from svn1.6 to svn 1.7.
When running "git svn dcommit". I got an assert in the middle of it:

```
R   Demos/myProject/Mac/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Base.prefab => Demos/myProject/UnityProject/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Base.prefab
    R   Demos/myProject/Mac/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Chunks.prefab => Demos/myProject/UnityProject/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Chunks.prefab
    R   Demos/myProject/Mac/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Crazysparks.prefab => Demos/myProject/UnityProject/Assets/Frameworks/Detonator/Prefab Examples/Detonator-Crazysparks.prefab
Assertion failed: (svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)), function uri_skip_ancestor, file subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c, line 1519.
error: git-svn died of signal 6
```

I read somewhere about having spaces in paths will cause svn1.7 to complaint but it does not explain why it didn't fail under the first path encountered that has spaces in it, see above.

I also tried this tip
[git-svn died of signal 10 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503219/git-svn-died-of-signal-10-on-osx)
with the hope that mismatch of lib versions could have been the fault, but it didn't work.

I'm in a hurry to check in something so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while. I finally found a work around to this problem:

Have a pure svn working copy, merge all changes from my git repository manually, and commit all my changes via svn directly.

Then return to my git svn working copy, run "git svn rebase". If there were added files, I need to remove existing files form git svn working copy first to avoid having error:

```
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
rebase refs/remotes/git-svn: command returned error: 1
```

After rebasing succeeds, I stopped getting the signal 6 errors.

Hope git team can fix this crash soon.